# Fire PropertyChanged for derived properties when parent property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

Basically, I have an image with a height in PX and in MM (for printing). As a "derived" property, I have the µm / px value:

```
public int HeightPX { get { return _HeightPX; } private set { _HeightPX = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
public int HeightMM { get { return _HeightMM; } set { _HeightMM = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
public double MUpPX { get {return HeightPX != 0 ?  HeightMM * 1000 / HeightPX :  0; } }
```

All of them are displayed in a WPF Textbox via a binding.

```
Text="{Binding ImageThing.MUpPX, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

However, when changing `HeightPX`or `HeightMM`, obviously, `MUpPX` changes, but does not fire an `PropertyChanged` event and is thus not updated in the GUI.

How can I achieve this? Can I somehow listen for the `PropertyChanged` Events of `Height` in `MUpPX` and then fire the corresponding event?

I would like to avoid firing the event from `Height`, because there may / will be other derived properties and it would not be a very clean abstraction if I have to take care of every derived property in the "parent" ones.

Comment: Take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466315/wpf-inotifypropertychanged-and-derived-properties-on-different-objects/54560230#54560230). I provided an answer there that contains an example of an attribute based approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MUpPX))` whenever you want to update the UI.

If you don't want to do this in the setters of the `Height*` properties, you could do it in your `RaisePropertyChanged` method, e.g.:

```
public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        if (caller == nameof(HeightPX) || caller == nameof(HeightMM))
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MUpPX)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to keep it all in one place? I mean, this is alright, but I would still rather like to keep all the code for `MUpPX`  in one place. Is it possible to somehow listen for events from the property itself?

Comment: Well, no. A property is just a mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a field. It is not set "in one place". This solution does keep the logic of refreshing the property in one place though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Your solution works, so I will accept it. Not perectly elegant, but if it is not possible, it's not possible. And better than calling `PropertyChanged` in every setter.